# How to convert a long array to an int array with lossy conversion

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm currently doing some realtime audio processing. I would like to convert a long[] to an int[]. The conversion should be lossy, e.g. if the long value is bigger than int.MaxValue, the result should be int.MaxValue.

I'm also interested in a conversion of byte[] to long[], where the byte[] contains 32bit integers.

Since it's realtime audio processing, performance is key.

What the best way to do this?

Comment: "_e.g. if the long value is bigger than int.MaxValue, the result should be int.MaxValue._" Does it mean you accept that the resulting audio can possibly suffer clipping?

Comment: Yes, clipping is supposed to happen

Comment: "Since it's realtime audio processing, performance is key." - have you measured if a simple solution like a for loop would be (in)sufficient?

Comment: Since I don't have any algorithm yet, I couldn't do any analysis

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know whether this will be your perf blocker or not, I suggest you to start using a naive solution first:

```
int[] intArray = longArray
  .Select(l => (int)(Math.Max(int.MinValue, Math.Min(l, int.MaxValue))))
  .ToArray();
```

An optimized version could replace the first half of the long array with the int array compressed in low/high parts of longs and use special access code to access a value. That would eliminate the need for allocating new memory which would boost performance.